# Google Appscript Authorization Error: 403 access denied

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, authorization, http-status-code-403

I am trying to run a simple script on my data in google sheets, but for some reason I'm not able to allow the script to access the sheet (I'm the owner of both). I tried to change **oauth** in google cloud services, but still nothing. Any ideas?

Here is the script im trying to run:

```
    function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart != 0) return;
  var newCheckbox = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();
  newCheckbox.requireCheckbox()
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  e.range.offset(0,10).setDataValidation(newCheckbox);
```

[image: Here is the error I'm getting after i try to sign in]

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you have to add yourself as test user in the GCP.

Comment: I'm sure this will fail because `e` is `undefined` but try running the onEdit() from the script editor.  That should authorize you for any services that are used in your script.  Then try it from the sheet.

Comment: not the answer to you question but e.range.columnStart will never be equal to zero so your script will never get pass the return and it will fire on every edit to any cell in the spreadsheet.